# Converting a table into XML then reverting into XML using Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

I need to convert a hard-coded HTML table into an XML. I am able to convert the HTML table into XML for which the coded is shown below. Now, I need to convert back that same XML file into HTML table in the same program. Can anyone please help me out with that. Thanks

Code is:

```
<body>
<!--Table begins-->
<table id="tb" border="1px" cellpadding="5px" cellspacing="5px">
<tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Country</th>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>ABC</td>
    <td>DEF</td>
    <td>GHI</td>
    <td>JKL</td>
    <td>MNO</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>PQR</td>
    <td>STU</td>
    <td>VWX</td>
    <td>AGC</td>
    <td>FSW</td>

</tr>
</table>
<!--Table ends here-->

  <script>
  $(function(){
    var xml = "";
        xml+= '<?xml version= "1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
        xml+= '<root>';

        $('tr:not(:first)').each(function(j, tr)
        {
        $tr = $(tr);
    xml += '<comp>';

    var index1 = $.trim($tr.find('td:first').text());
    xml += '<name>'+index1+'';
    xml += '</name>';

    var index2 = $.trim($tr.find('td:nth-child(2)').text());
    xml += '<company>'+index2+'';
    xml += '</company>';

            var index3 = $.trim($tr.find('td:nth-child(3)').text());
    xml += '<country>'+index3+'';
    xml += '</country>';

    var index4 = $.trim($tr.find('td:nth-child(4)').text());
    xml += '<fname>'+index4+'';
    xml += '</fname>';

    var index5 = $.trim($tr.find('td:last').text());
    xml += '<lname>'+index5+'';
    xml += '</lname>';

    xml += '</comp>';
});
xml+= '</root>';

console.log(xml);
});
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: You may use XSLT that takes a XML file and displays it according to a specific template. i.e: the template that you want for your table.

Comment: Check the following quick tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/default.asp

Comment: Thanks mrida......Can you post the code for that plz. I am new to XSLT.

Comment: I have the entire xml in a variable now. I want to parse that XML to form an HTML table. And also there is a language constraint which is already mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

This code may help you

```
<html>
<head>
<title ></title>
<script type ="text/javascript">
function loadXMLDoc(filename) {
    if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");

    }
    else {
        xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    xhttp.open("GET", filename, false);
    try { xhttp.responseType = "msxml-document" } catch (err) { } // Helping IE11
    xhttp.send("");
    return xhttp.responseXML;
}

function displayResult() {

    xml = loadXMLDoc("youXMLfile name");

    xsl = loadXMLDoc("yourXSLfilename");


    // code for IE
    if (window.ActiveXObject || xhttp.responseType == "msxml-document") {
        ex = xml1.transformNode(xsl);
        document.getElementById("example").innerHTML = ex;
    }
        // code for Chrome, Firefox, Opera, etc.
    else if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument) {
        xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
        xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsl);
        resultDocument = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xml1, document);           
        document.getElementById("example").appendChild(resultDocument);
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="displayResult()">
<div id="example" />
</body>
</html>
```

you can refer this code [on this link](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_transformation.asp)

Comment: Prasanna- can you provide me a working solution by integrating your code with mine in a jsfiddle if possible. Thanks

Comment: I have already seen this code on the provided link. I am new to XSLT, so any help would be great.

Comment: How are you picking the data from the xml named string variable?

Comment: @ranger sorry buddy i am not getting time to work on it but just got the fiddle that will help you [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5TNH9/)

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to go to fiddle right now but I have created xsl for you check this out.

```
  <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
  <body>

    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th style="text-align:left">Name</th>
        <th style="text-align:left">Company</th>
        <th style="text-align:center">Country</th>
        <th style="text-align:center">First Name</th>
        <th style="text-align:center">Last Name</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="Root/comp">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
          </td>
          <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="Company"/>
          </td>
          <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="Country"/>
          </td>
          <td>
            <xsl:value-of select ="FirstName"/>
          </td>
          <td>
            <xsl:value-of select ="LastName"/>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Its not populating the table. It just displays the column headings only. What should I do to populate the table with the content. My entire xml is in string format & I need to convert it back to HTML tabular format.

Comment: @ranger it is just the xsl file in which we define how result should look like please use my first answer as html code and in that '("yourXSLfilename")' as the file name of the xsl file of which i have craeted for you

Comment: Please see the "console.log(xml)" statement present in the 5th last line of my code. Now in this variable, I have the entire xml file in the string format. I want to generate a HTML table from this xml named variable.